# Why use BeautifulSoup find_all method will results in an error(list index out of range)?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pyspider

The html like this:

```
<div id="market-summary">
  ...
   <li>
     <span class="title">title1</span>
     <span class="subtitle">subtitle1</span>
   <li>
   <li>
     <span class="title">title2</span>
     <span class="subtitle">subtitle2</span>
   <li>
   <li>
     <span class="title">title1</span>
     <span class="subtitle">subtitle1</span>
   <li>
  ...
</div>
```

python code almost like this:

```
........
if soup.select("#market-summary")[0].findAll('li'):
    prices = soup.select("#market-summary")[0].findAll('li')
    if prices is not None and len(prices) > 0:
        price = [
            {'size': x.find(class_="title").get_text(),
             'price': x.find(class_="subtitle").get_text()}
            for x in prices
        ]
        return price
    return 'price?'
return 'li?'
........
........
```

Now I start running this program the program is running. and The console was printing the price but just two or three mins, I got error message:

> 'IndexError: list index out of range'

and program interrupted and i tried it again and again. the always `'IndexError: list index out of range'` why the didn't show me 'price?' or 'li?'. Case BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the page you are parsing does not have any elements with id `market-summary`
If you check the error produced again, you might find that the error is occurring in line 1 i.e.
`if soup.select("#market-summary")[0]` or line 2 i.e. `prices = soup.select("#market-summary")[0].findAll('li')`

Comment: if not have `#market-summary` i think it not only return 'li?'  but also the program is keep running i.e 
`  
if soup.find('h1'):
    shop_name = soup.find('h1').get_text()
    return shop_name
return 'not shop_name'
`
if not find `h1` The console remind me 'not shop_name', program didn't interrupted, the still print `h1` text